# Mutex in Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, synchronization

I have a method that work like this:

1. Given an id, extract object data from database
2. Based in last data saved in object, process information in an associated file
3. Update object in database

That method is in a web service, so many clients could call the method at very same time. If they pass diferent ids there is no problem, but if they use the same id they can duplicate information in file.

I can't lock file or database, I need a mutex for threads using only the id. Maybe with synchronized methods, mark the id as used and release it after update object.

I am not sure how to do it. Maybe with a list of used ids but, how can I block and notify to a thread in web service?

Thank you

Comment: Could you use a sequential number in the database, that the process checks and increments before beginning step 2?  So, for example, when I get the object, the sequential number on it is 51.  When I start processing the file, I check that it's still 51 in the database and update it to 52.  If another thread also retrieved it when it was 51, then tries to run the processing, it will see that I have changed the sequence number to 52, and fail.  Would something like this meet your requirements?  If so, I'll expand this comment and turn it into an answer.

Comment: I can, but in step 2 processing is costly and it's preferable don't repeat it if not necessary

Comment: Yes, but with what I'm suggesting, a thread won't start step 2 if another thread has already started it.  The hard part is working out what to do if the first thread is interrupted.

Comment: Oh it's true. Then I would have to read from database twice in a row? I am not sure, also it isn't exactly a database but a search engine and sometimes it's a little slow to update :(

Comment: Tell me about this search engine?  Is it part of your application?  Is there some object in it that you can synchronize on?

Comment: I use elasticsearch with Java API, and I realized that sometimes it takes some seconds before update data in it, so even if I checked in synchronized method (at step 2 or 3) it's possible I see older data.

Comment: OK, I know nothing about elasticsearch.  But it looks like your original idea of keeping a collection of locks within your application looks like it might be the way to go.  How about using the `Collections.synchronizedSet` method to wrap a `HashSet` of `id` values?

Comment: Talking with you I realized something. Initially I thought lock the thread and unlock it (monitoring the id), so all the threads would pass by step 2 and 3 (with different processing). But I can simply do nothing if id is taken. Thus, with only check the synchronized set I can take a decision. Thank you! :D

Comment: OK, happy to have helped, even if I couldn't supply an actual "answer".